# Ubuntu 18.04 external monitor shows some app "zoomed"

Tags: 18.04, xrandr, external-monitor

I have new ThinkPad T495, with the Ryzen 7 3700U. I installed Ubuntu server 18.04, with HWE stacks. 
The resolution of the laptop's screen is 1920x1080, while the resolution of the external monitor is 1920x1200. I had to manually add the last one, using:

```
xrandr --newmode  "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-0 1920x1200_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1200_60.00
```

because it wasn't automatically recognized by ubuntu.
Everything is working almost fine, except for some applications (i.e. Virtualbox, Rstudio) that look like extremely "zoomed". I am currently running i3 window manager and Compton, but the same thing happens with ubuntu+Gnome, so I think it should be something related to xrandr instead of to the specific desktop environment.
What should I do?

[RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCyTJ.png)